# check if value of one column lies between the range of another column(array) in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe where I need to compare a few values and deduce a few things out of it.

For instance,

my DF

```
CITY DAY MONTH TAG RANGE     VALUE  RANK
A    1    01    A   [50, 90]   55     1
A    2    02    B   [30, 40]   34     3
A    1    03    A   [05, 10]   15    20
A    1    04    B   [50, 60]   11    10 
A    1    05    B   [50, 60]   54    4
```

I have to check , for every row if the value of "VALUE" lies between the "RANGE". Here, arr[0] is the lower limit and arr[1] is the upper limit.

I need to create a new DF such that,

NEW-DF

```
TAG  Positive  Negative
A     1          1
B     2          1
```

1. If the "value" lies between the given range and the rank < 5 then I would add it to "positive"
2. If the value doesnt lie in the given range , then it is a negative
3. If the value lies in the given range, but the rank > 5, then I would count it as negative

"Positive" and "Negative" is nothing but the count of the values fulfilling either conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `element_at` to get the elements at each position and compare them to the corresponding value in each row, along with the rank condition, and then perform a `groupby` with `sum` on the tag:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

range_df = df.withColumn('in_range', (F.element_at('range', 1).cast(IntegerType()) < F.col('value')) & 
                                     (F.col('value') < F.element_at('range', 2).cast(IntegerType())) &
                                     (F.col('rank') < 5))

range_df.show()

grouped_df = range_df.groupby('tag').agg(F.sum(F.col('in_range').cast(IntegerType())).alias('total_positive'), 
                                         F.sum((~F.col('in_range')).cast(IntegerType())).alias('total_negative'))

grouped_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|tag|   range|value|rank|in_range|
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|  A|[50, 90]|   55|   1|    true|
|  B|[30, 40]|   34|   3|    true|
|  A|[05, 10]|   15|  20|   false|
|  B|[50, 60]|   11|  10|   false|
|  B|[50, 60]|   54|   4|    true|
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+

+---+--------------+--------------+
|tag|total_positive|total_negative|
+---+--------------+--------------+
|  B|             2|             1|
|  A|             1|             1|
+---+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I just gave a small doubt since I'm new to python as well as spark. 
I'm trying to use a '~' to match negative conditions (for something that doesn't fall in a particular range). 

    `range_df = df.withColumn('in_range', (~ F.element_at('range', 
    1).cast(IntegerType( . 
    < F.col('value')) & 
    (~ F.col('value') < F.element_at('range', 2).cast(IntegerType())) &
    (F.col('rank') < 5))`

However this throws a data type mismatch error! since it returns a integer type whereas the not operator expects a boolean!

Comment: @nikitap I am slightly confused. That is not my answer, is it?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know how do I go about writing a condition when a certain "value" doesnt fall in between the "range". I need that as well since I'm adding a few more conditions to this.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, I figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: @nikitap Ah, so you are asking an unconnected question? In that case, I think it's just where you put the `~` (it has pretty low precedence, so you need to use brackets judiciously). Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a UDF first to process the range :

```
val df = Seq(("A","1","01","A","[50,90]","55","1")).toDF("city","day","month","tag","range","value","rank")

+----+---+-----+---+-------+-----+----+
|city|day|month|tag|  range|value|rank|
+----+---+-----+---+-------+-----+----+
|   A|  1|   01|  A|[50,90]|   55|   1|
+----+---+-----+---+-------+-----+----+


  def checkRange(range : String,rank : String, value : String) : String = {
    val rangeProcess = range.dropRight(1).drop(1).split(",")
    if (rank.toInt > 5){
      "negative"
    } else {
      if (value > rangeProcess(0) && value < rangeProcess(1)){
        "positive"
      } else {
        "negative"
      }
    }
  }

  val checkRangeUdf = udf(checkRange _)

df.withColumn("Result",checkRangeUdf(col("range"),col("rank"),col("value"))).show()

+----+---+-----+---+-------+-----+----+--------+
|city|day|month|tag|  range|value|rank|  Result|
+----+---+-----+---+-------+-----+----+--------+
|   A|  1|   01|  A|[50,90]|   55|   1|positive|
+----+---+-----+---+-------+-----+----+--------+


val result = df.withColumn("Result",checkRangeUdf(col("range"),col("rank"),col("value"))).groupBy("city","Result").count.show

+----+--------+-----+
|city|  Result|count|
+----+--------+-----+
|   A|positive|    1|
+----+--------+-----+
```